# Is it possible to make use of a value returned from a method called by a delegate?

Tags: actionscript-3

While experimenting with a basic coding stuff, I wondered, if a value returned by a method called by a delegate, could be used or captured. In other words, where will the return value will go ?

For example :

```
class Main extends Sprite
{
   public var mc:MyMc;

   function Main()
  {
      mc.addEventListener( "myClick" , myClick);

  }

  function myClick(e:Event):String  //returning a string 
  {
     return "What happens to this return value ???" 
  }


}



class MyMc extends MovieClip
{

   function MyMc()
  {
      addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK , onClick);

  }

  function onClick(e:Event):String  //returning a string 
  {
     dispatchEvent(new Event("myClick")); 
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's not possible to do, but, there are at least some ways to implement the logic similar to what you've told about.

For example, you may call a method of a dispatcher, from a listener method:

```
class Main extends Sprite
{
   public var mc:MyMc;

   function Main()
   {
      mc.addEventListener("myClick" , myClick);
   }

   function myClick(e:Event):void
   {
      mc.specialMethod("some string");
   }
}

class MyMc extends MovieClip
{
   function MyMc()
   {
      addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , onClick);
   }

   function onClick(e:Event):void
   {
      dispatchEvent(new Event("myClick")); 
   }

   public function specialMethod(param:String):void
   {
      // Do something to the param
   }
}
```

Also, you may think about dispatching an event from the Main class, and listen to it in the MyMc class, or pass a callback, which returns a string, from Main to the MyMc.

Answer (score 0):

It's according to you and your needs to return something from the listener function because normally [it must return nothing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) :

> ... This function must accept an Event object as its only parameter and must return nothing, ...

but you can of course get the returned value(s), take a look on this little example :

```
var light_on:Boolean = false; 

btn_light_on.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_on_onPress);
btn_light_off.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_off_onPress);

function btn_on_onPress(e:MouseEvent): Boolean {
    light_on = true;
    if(e.target === btn_light_off){
        light_on = false;       
    }
    return light_on;
}

function btn_off_onPress(e:MouseEvent): void {
    trace('The light is', btn_on_onPress(e) ? 'on' : 'off');
}
```

Hope that can help.